# RegionIntersection: extra intersections

Tags: graphics, intersection

I have got an array of points, which can be represented as a ListLinePlot. Then I am trying to find the number of intersections of this ListLinePlot with a certain line. Obviously, in the demonstrated case the number of intersections should be two, but I get 5 points as a result. RegionIntersection gives the same result. How can I fix that? I can't create and solve the system of equations, representing an intersection condition, because there is a large number of arrays to be investigated and their general appearance is unknown. The problem is that I should know the exact number of intersections. Thanks in advance.

My code is (sol is an above-mentioned array of points):

```
lst1 = Sort[sol];

lst2 = Table[{x, Max[Sort[sol[[All, 2]]]] - (Max[Sort[sol[[All, 2]]]] - Min[Sort[sol[[All, 2]]]])/5}, 
{x, Min[Sort[sol[[All, 1]]]], Max[Sort[sol[[All, 1]]]], 0.5}];

plot = ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}, PlotRange -> All]

l = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@plot
```

[image: example]

The concrete example of the "sol" array:

```
{{7.05547, -2.46723}, {1.86965, 
  1.1145}, {5.99004, -0.731189}, {3.12849, 
  1.61209}, {7.16644, -2.67133}, {1.74237, 
  0.984025}, {7.02438, -2.41082}, {1.90557, 1.1482}, {5.23746, 
  0.238673}, {3.98266, 1.32496}, {6.38239, -1.32259}, {2.66365, 
  1.57629}, {7.25692, -2.84091}, {1.63982, 
  0.865836}, {7.27641, -2.87781}, {1.61788, 
  0.838986}, {7.27742, -2.87971}, {1.61675, 
  0.83759}, {7.27695, -2.87882}, {1.61728, 
  0.838239}, {7.27717, -2.87925}, {1.61703, 
  0.837928}, {7.27707, -2.87905}, {1.61714, 
  0.838075}, {7.27712, -2.87914}, {1.61709, 
  0.838006}, {7.27709, -2.8791}, {1.61711, 
  0.838039}, {7.2771, -2.87912}, {1.6171, 
  0.838023}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.83803}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.6171, 
  0.838027}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 
  0.838028}, {7.2771, -2.87911}, {1.61711, 0.838028}}
```

Comment: Provide a set of points that demonstrates this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option `` Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False ``

```
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot, Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
```

> ```
> {{4.68871, 0.71373}}
> ```

***Where do the extra points come from?***

Repeated consecutive points count as intersections. There are two such points in `lst1`:

```
Select[#[[2]] > 1 &]@Tally[lst1]
```

> ```
> {{{1.61711, 0.838028}, 145}, {{7.2771, -2.87911}, 147}}
> ```

If you remove duplicates from `lst1`, we get get a single intersection without having to use the option `` Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False ``:

```
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections @
 ListLinePlot[{DeleteDuplicates@lst1, lst2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
>  {{4.68871, 0.71373}}
> ```

By the way, [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) does not include self-intersections and gives a single point:

```
RegionIntersection[Line@lst1, Line@lst2]
```

> ```
>   Point[{{4.68871, 0.71373}}]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've forgotten to mention that I should know the exact number of intersections.

Comment: @Tanya, where should the second intersection be?

Comment: Thank you once again! After your addition all became clear. After deleting duplicates everything is alright :)

Answer (score 3):

```
line1 = Line[lst1];
line2 = Line[lst2];
RegionIntersection[line1, line2]

(* Point[{{4.68871, 0.71373}}]*)
```